# mysql and passenger - error “library not loaded”

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, passenger, rvm

Like Meltemi posted on this post: [Passenger error "library not loaded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254128/passenger-error-library-not-loaded) i get the same error. but the answer posted does not help!

```
dlopen(/Users/andi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9):
Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/andi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Users/andi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

Im operating with RVM 1.2.6, Rails 3.0.3, Ruby 1.9.2. The server worked fine, till i switched my repository from svn to git. It seems very strange to me that this change effected my installation.

```
$bundle list
Gems included by the bundle:
...
  * mysql2 (0.2.7)
...


$ /usr/local/mysql-5.5.8-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysql --version
/usr/local/mysql-5.5.8-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.8, for osx10.6 (i386) using readline 5.1
```

thx for response!

EDIT: solution:

according to [rails server fails to start with mysql2 using rvm & ruby 1.9.2-p0 on OSX 10.6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512362/rails-server-fails-to-start-with-mysql2-using-rvm-ruby-1-9-2-p0-on-osx-10-6-5) and http://freddyandersen.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/mysql-5-5-snow-leopard-and-rails/

this command solves my problem:
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.16.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle

Comment: Looks like you have MySQL client v14 installed, but ruby is looking for v16?

Comment: Hmm.. I see. and where can I change this config? Or would it be better to upgrade mysql?

Comment: Not sure, and I'm not 100% that that's actually the problem. Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512362/rails-server-fails-to-start-with-mysql2-using-rvm-ruby-1-9-2-p0-on-osx-10-6-5

Comment: tried this: sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.16.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
according to: http://freddyandersen.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/mysql-5-5-snow-leopard-and-rails/

Comment: thx Thilo, we found the same hint ;) but it didn't resolve my problem

Comment: *argh... taking the right mysql gem solves the problem: sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.16.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle thx to you thilo!

Comment: As far as Stack Overflow etiquette goes, you should post your solution as an answer to the question and accept it. It will give you rep and will make the community happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution:

according to rails server fails to start with mysql2 using rvm & ruby 1.9.2-p0 on OSX 10.6.5 and http://freddyandersen.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/mysql-5-5-snow-leopard-and-rails/

this command solves my problem: sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.16.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle